# Matlab error: regarding 'compile_mex;' command

Tags: matlab, shell, ssh, compilation, mex

To all,

I'm trying to run a makefile using the 'mex' command through Matlab. However,
when I try to run my test .m script using 'compile_mex;" I get the following error:

```
>> compile_mex
xcodebuild: error: SDK "macosx10.7" cannot be located.
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "clang++", not a developer tool or in PATH

mex: compile of ' "mex/perform_nlmeans_mex.cpp"' failed.
```

I've read through a couple of sources that a shell script may need to be written 
to physically add the clang++ utility through a library that I need to import into 
Matlab directly. Does anyone know how to fix/perform this? A sample or example shell
script and directions on how to use that script within or in coordination with 
Matlab would be great if anyone can provide me this. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still waiting to receive help on this question. Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: See my answer here: [Cannot run Matlab Mex files on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 with Xcode Version 4.3.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309064/cannot-run-matlab-mex-files-on-mac-os-x-lion-10-7-5-with-xcode-version-4-3-2/20434544#20434544).

Answer (score 1):

A temporary workaround is given [here](http://www.cyberbotics.com/forum?message=2406). Effectively it amounts to getting MATLAB to use a different SDK (as the 10.7 SDK is removed in Mavericks). From the link:

Just for clarity in case someone else runs into the same issue, I
changed four lines in `mexopts.sh`:

> ```
> #            CC='xcrun  -sdk macosx10.7  clang'
>         CC='xcrun  -sdk macosx10.8  clang' 
>
> #            MW_SDK_TEMP="find `xcode-select -print-path` -name MacOSX10.7.sdk"
>         MW_SDK_TEMP="find `xcode-select -print-path` -name MacOSX10.8.sdk" 
>
> #            MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.7'
>         MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.8' 
>
> #            CXX='xcrun  -sdk macosx10.7  clang++'
>         CXX='xcrun  -sdk macosx10.8  clang++'
> ```

I also had to do "mex -setup" from inside matlab in order to copy
 mexopts.sh to my user directory.

When I did this change I directly edited `~/.matlab/R2013a/mexopts.sh` rather than `.matlab/R2013a/mexopts.sh` – I felt this was slightly safer. It also removes the requirement to rerun `mex -setup`, but of course this means that the file can be overwritten.

For 10.9:

> ```
>         CC='xcrun  -sdk macosx10.9  clang' 
>         MW_SDK_TEMP="find `xcode-select -print-path` -name MacOSX10.9.sdk" 
>         MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.9' 
>         CXX='xcrun  -sdk macosx10.9  clang++'
> ```